# Rerender Html page after PHP function call

Tags: php, html, web-services, post, get

I currently have this login page.

```
<form action='http://localhost:8080/iSchedj/API/api.php' method='post'>
<fieldset>

<p>
<label for='username'>Username</label>
<input type='text' id='username' name='username' value='' maxlength='20' />
</p>

<p>
<label for='password'>Password</label>
<input type='password' id='password' name='password' value='' maxlength='40' />
</p>

<p>
<input type='hidden' name='form_token' value='<?php echo $form_token; ?>' />
<input type='submit' name='login' id='login' value='Login' />
</p>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

On submit, I have a function on the server-side where I analyze the data and check if there are any issues.

Problem is, I would like to send a response back to the client and re render the login page if any issues occurred with a response saying 'Error on login'.

I am having an issue with the response part.

On the server side, I just run this when an error is found in the form

`header( 'Location: http://localhost:8080/iSchedj/index.php');
echo 'Incorrect Length for Password';`

which redirects the client to the login page. But how do I send the error message to the page as well? The echo message is no where to be found.

Comment: You could use `$_GET` and redirect the user with a GET-variable (for instance, `header( 'Location: http://localhost:8080/iSchedj/index.php?error_code=1');`. There might be other, better methods though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to the URL and display your error message via JavaScript.

```
header( 'Location: http://localhost:8080/iSchedj/index.php#error=1');
```

Your JS script will need to look at the `document.location.hash` and behave accordingly.

Comment: So how do I access the url information? I logged the $_SERVER global but I cant seem to find the fragment portion of the url

Comment: $_SERVER is the server-side. You need to do this on the client-side using JavaScript.